# Why is the Aruch Hashulchan on Even Haezer incomplete?

Tags: history, aruch-hashulchan

The [Aruch Hashulchan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruch_HaShulchan) is written on the whole Shulchan Aruch, and even has sections on Halacha that is not currently applicable (Aruch Hashulchan Ha'asid). Yet he never finished [Even Haezer](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9105&st=&pgnum=373).

Why?

Comment: He's also missing YD 123-182 and in most editions also YD 203-239. They were probably lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F#.D7.9E.D7.94.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.AA):

The Aruch HaShulchan was originally written and published in sets of approximately 20 simanim a piece. When its author died, he left the remaining packets to his daughter to finish publishing. Apparently, she never finished publishing some of the last booklets. No one has seen the manuscripts since.

Comment: While standard editions may not have them, I'm not sure if they were all actually lost. I think I remember seeing an edition that had (some of) the missing simanim.

Comment: @ArielK See [my comment on the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14301/why-is-the-aruch-hashulchan-on-even-haezer-incomplete/14311#comment26148_14301). But it seems most are lost.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/can-you-use-electricity-on-yom-tov/47260?noredirect=1#comment179961_47260

Answer (score 2):

The Aruch HaShulchan left all his manuscripts to his daughter, but then the war broke out, and they were sent to Israel. Included in his manuscripts were the Aruch HaShulchan He'asid, which was printed by Mossad Harav Kook; D'rashos kol ben Levi, which was printed; the second chelek of Or La'yesharim, which was not yet printed; and the rest of the Aruch HaShulchan, of which only Hilchos Nedarim was printed.

Comment: Do the manuscripts for the missing parts of Even HaEzer still exist?

Comment: What about the other halachos from Yoreh Deah?